# Outside element - close event - is not working - js

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, dom-events

I have made a delay open modal, everything is working except one function - close when clicked outside the modal - when I click out of the modal it does not close, please can You help me why?

This is js code with the line which is not working:

```
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick());

function outsideClick(event) {
    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = ('none');
    }
}
```

the whole modal is here: https://codepen.io/hubkubas/pen/wXpYwy

Comment: your event in outsideClick is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change event listener like this `window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);`

Answer (score 1):

Pass callback function like this (without brackets):

```
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
```

Then `outsideClick` will be called with default parameters and `event` won't be undefined.